# How to remap array keys (based on values) with PHP?

Tags: php, function

```
<?php

// get unordered array of Group objects
$groups = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Group');

$array = array();
// map array to $groupName => $groupObject
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $array[$group->getName()] = $group;
}
```

Is there a shorter way to do that in PHP?

> Note: Group names are unique, not empty strings.

I was thinking about `array_walk`, but I'm not sure if can replace the key somehow?

Comment: That looks pretty short to me.

Comment: Since this is a doctrine2-related question, check out DQL's index by: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#using-index-by

Comment: You can do nasty things with combining the array with a mapped array, but that won't be faster, and be more obscure. Your code example is fine, well readable for any other developer, and performs as well or even better then one-line-atrocities that are possible. I'd stick with this one.

Comment: @Maerlyn I know I could meddle with DQL to get the resulting array, but in this question I was interested if thats the easiest/most clean way to remap array keys.

Comment: @Wrikken hi, since I could not find (and noone posted) a better or shorter alternative, I'd gladly accept your comment if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no shorter/better way than the one posted in the question.